# How Do I Fade the Top or Bottom Edge of a SF Symbol in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, sf-symbols

I'm trying to recreate a visual, that consist of 3 SF Symbols.
The image in the middle is 100% solid no fade.
I would like to fade top edge of the top most image
and fade the bottom edge of the bottom most image.

I am using SF Symbols.

I would like to reproduce the following:

(fade top of image)

IMAGE

IMAGE

IMAGE

(fade bottom of image)

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Hard to answer - your question isn't vague at all IMHO but it's... well, first, can you be sure it can be done? I'm not even talking about SwiftUI, I'm talking UIKit. I *think* I have a mental picture of what you want, but could you supply an actual image? And yes, by that, I';m asking if you've seen this done with SFSymbols. Finally, if it *can* be done, have you considered what (a) SFSymbols are - vectors, (b) what CoreGraphics may bring to the table, (c) what CoreImage might do, but mostly (d) how constrained SwiftUI is currently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my alternate (without UIKit usage)

[image]

```
struct TestSFSymbolsFade: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "ant.fill").resizable()
            Image(systemName: "ant.fill").resizable()
            Image(systemName: "ant.fill").resizable()
        }
        .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [
            .init(color: .clear, location: 0),
            .init(color: .black, location: 0.25),
            .init(color: .black, location: 0.75),
            .init(color: .clear, location: 1)
        ]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .frame(width: 40, height: 160) // < just for demo, can be any or absent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, keep in mind that there are usage rules around SF Symbols. It may or may not be allowed to modify them in this way. In particular there is a list of ["As-Is" symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) that cannot be used for arbitrary purposes. But that doesn't change much about the answer.

The second thing to note is that SF Symbols are a strange beast between text and images. They often act like text, and they often [draw outside their frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580712/97337). That creates problems. <strike>You can fix that by forcing them to be real images as discussed in the linked answer.</strike>

```
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
let image = Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName:"star.fill", withConfiguration: config)!)
```

In the end, as long as you can get an `Image` that has the correct frame, the rest of this will work. It doesn't matter that it's a SF Symbol.

Asperi's answer explains how to fix this by using `resizable`.

```
let image = Image(systemName: "star.fill").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

(I've added `aspectRatio` so it doesn't distort.)

First, define your Gradient. This is how the fade will work, and you can configure it with a set of colors or individual color stops. The only thing that matters here is the opacity.

```
let fade =  Gradient(colors: [Color.clear, Color.black])
```

(See Asperi's answer for an example using stops, which give you more control over the fade.)

With that, you can apply this gradient as a mask:

```
let fade =  Gradient(colors: [Color.clear, Color.black])
let image = Image(systemName: "star.fill")
    .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(height: 48)

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image
                .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: fade, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            image
            image
                .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: fade, startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
        }
    }
}
```

This raises issues about sizing. This approach is a flexible stack. It will grow to fill whatever container it's put in. You may want to constrain it a couple of ways.

First, you can decide the height of the entire stack by putting a frame on it:

```
    VStack {
        image
            .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: fade, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        image
        image
            .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: fade, startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top))
    }.frame(height: 128)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you could fix the size of each image instead:

```
let image = Image(systemName: "star.fill")
    .resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 48)
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: Three symbols with fading at top and bottom]